# find a file given string criteria in batch

Tags: string, file, batch-file

I got a variable containing some words, e.g `KEYWORDS ="Blue Blond Brown White Black Eyes Hair Skin"`, and another containing only some of them, e.g
`MYWORDS="BLUE BROWN EYES HAIR"`

I have some files in my directory, e.g

```
BlueEyesBlondHair.txt
BrownEyesBlondHair.txt
BlueEyesBrownHair.txt
BlueEyesBrownHairWhiteSkin.txt
BlueEyes.txt
BrownHair.txt
BrownEyes.txt
GreenEyesBlondHair.txt
```

How can I retrieve the file whose name contains all the words from variable `MYWORDS`, and no other?

NOTE: this is a completely made up example, but I think it sticks well enough to my reality. Please do as if everything was in uppercase letters.

Comment: This site is not really here to provide you with a methodology for performing an entire task.

Comment: @Compo hell, you're right. I've tried to get as close as possible to the part of the task that was bothering me, but then I kept adding explanation and now it's too much. I'm gonna refactor this.

Comment: is your intention to use the exact match on the content of the file, when using grep, or the filename itself? in other words, is the idea to do: `grep -l BlueEyesBrownHair *.txt` or to do: `grep -l %STRING% BlueEyesBrownHair.txt` ?

Comment: @Gerhard: not sure I understand your question. I'm using grep to get the filename of all txt files containing the string, so `grep -l %STRING% *.txt`. I can't know that it's BlueEyesBrownHair that I need, since this information is given by %STRING%

Comment: It's a made up question, @Gerhard, there is no solution to it. Take the example, if `%STRING%` could be split up, as if using `find.exe`, e.g. `dir "*.txt" | find /i "blue" | find /i "hair" | find /i "brown" | find /i "eyes"`, you'd get only `BlueEyesBrownHair.txt` and `BlueEyesBrownHairWhiteSkin.txt` through. But it appears that `BlueEyesBrownHairWhiteSkin.txt` isn't wanted because it carries characters which weren't in `%STRING%`. Can we assume that the requirement is to retrieve the files with the least characters in their filenames?

Comment: @Compo yes, retrieve the file with the least characters in its filename would do the trick.

Comment: I think I got rid of all unecessary stuff. Should be more clear now.

Comment: @Compo, I see yes. Ok, so then it would be a case of ensuring the string contains all the words, in any order, then take the file with the least amount of characters.

Comment: Okay @Ablia, so you need to search for existing questions and answers which count the number of characters in a filename, and/or selects the strings/substrings containing the least amount of characters, because its possible to match twenty four filenames from those four matches.

Comment: @Compo yeah, that's what I was doing since you mentioned the "least character in filename", but I didn't found anything usefull yet :( I think I'll try to do it "backway": getting rid of all files that contains words I don't want first. Then i'll just have to find the one that contains all the words I want...it may be easier, idk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting puzzle.

Your white-list words obviously can occur in any order, that makes it a bit difficult, but not unsolvable:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM ---- only to generate testfiles: ---
for %%a in (
BlueEyesBlondHair.txt
BrownEyesBlondHair.txt
BlueEyesBrownHair.txt
BlueEyesBrownHairWhiteSkin.txt
BlueEyes.txt
BrownHair.txt
BrownEyes.txt
GreenEyesBlondHair.txt
LongHairBlueShirtBrownEyes.txt
CompletelyUnrelatedFile.txt
) do break>"%%a"
REM ---- end generate testfiles ----

set "KEYWORDS=Blue Blond Brown White Black Eyes Hair Skin"
set "MYWORDS=BLUE BROWN EYES HAIR"
REM generate exclude-list:
set "NONWORDS=%KEYWORDS%"
for %%a in (%MYWORDS%) do set "NONWORDS=!NONWORDS:%%a=!"
rem echo %NONWORDS%

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
  set /a c1=c2=0
  set "name=%%~na"
  for %%b in (%MYWORDS%) do (
    REM increment counter1 [number of words in MYWORDS]:
    set /a c1+=1
    REM increment counter2 [number of those words in the filename]
    if not "!name:%%b=!" == "!name!" set /a c2+=1
  )
  if !c1! == !c2! (
    echo %%a has all of MYWORDS
    echo %%a|findstr "%NONWORDS%" >nul|| (
      echo %%a has none of NONWORDS
    ) && (
      echo +++ %%a has all of MYWORDS and none of NONWORDS
    ) 
  ) else (
    echo %%a has not all of MYWORDS
  )
)
```

Output of this code:

```
BlueEyes.txt has not all of MYWORDS
BlueEyesBlondHair.txt has not all of MYWORDS
BlueEyesBrownHair.txt has all of MYWORDS
BlueEyesBrownHair.txt has none of NONWORDS
+++ BlueEyesBrownHair.txt has all of MYWORDS and none of NONWORDS
BlueEyesBrownHairWhiteSkin.txt has all of MYWORDS
BrownEyes.txt has not all of MYWORDS
BrownEyesBlondHair.txt has not all of MYWORDS
BrownHair.txt has not all of MYWORDS
CompletelyUnrelatedFile.txt has not all of MYWORDS
GreenEyesBlondHair.txt has not all of MYWORDS
LongHairBlueShirtBrownEyes.txt has all of MYWORDS
LongHairBlueShirtBrownEyes.txt has none of NONWORDS
+++ LongHairBlueShirtBrownEyes.txt has all of MYWORDS and none of NONWORDS
```

Obviously, adapt the `echo`s to your needs or skip those you don't need at all (I made it a bit verbose for better troubleshooting).

Comment: This is great! :) I was focusing too much on getting all the words and a good regex and then do the search in one command, never thought about just testing the filenames one after another...Thank you!

Comment: REGEX is very limited in `cmd`, so not really an option here. The above approach feels awkward and not elegant, but I can't think of any better logic to do it. Gerhard's approach to `find...|find...|find...etc.` would be faster, but it means, you have to hardcode your word-list into the code - not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting a method out there, though, you could use `findstr`s regular expression instead of all the `find commands.. This is really just a demonstration:

```
@echo off & set prev=100
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.txt ^|find /i "blue" ^|find /i "brown"^|find /i "eyes"^|find /i "hair"') do echo %%i>_&for %%a IN (_) do (
   set /a len=%%~za-2
   if !len! lss !prev! (
     set prev=!len!
     set "file=%%i"
  )
)
echo !file! & (del _ /Q)>nul 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks. This would need to split my variable, however; I know how to do it in a FOR loop but I'm not sure I could set multiple variables containing each one word of the first one, especially since I don't know how much words will be in my variable... but it's still a start, thanks for your time.
Can you explain the `za`in your `set /a len=%%~za-2` ?

Comment: then use `findstr`'s regular expression to do the search for you. This was simply demonstration. To learn about variable expansion, see `for /?`

Comment: ofc, I was trying to understand how to do it with findstr, and then I found that multiple search strings must just be separated with spaces -_- lost another hour. 
Anyway, found the `za` thing, thank you. This would be a great help even in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it that doesn't need to check for the filename length: findstr has a /v option that allows it to search for things that do NOT match the pattern.

Since I have both `KEYWORDS`and `MYWORDS` variables, I can easily make a third one named `BADWORDS`, containing all the words that are in `KEYWORDS` but not  in `MYWORDS`.

Following the example, we have `BADWORD= BLOND WHITE BLACK SKIN`

Then it'll be enough to do a simple:

```
dir /b *.txt | findstr /i /C:"BLUE" /C:"BROWN" /C:"HAIR" /C:"EYES" | findstr /i /v "%BADWORDS%"
```

to get the filenames which contains all the words from `MYWORDS` but no other.

However, this still need to split the variable `MYWORDS`, just as in @Gerhard answer.

An alternative would be to modify `MYWORDS` like this:

```
set MYNEWWORDS=%MYWORDS: =.*%
```

and then do

```
dir /b *.txt | findstr /i /R /C:"%MYNEWWORDS%" | findstr /i /v "%BADWORDS%"
```

This will search for filenames containing ALL the words from `MYWORDS`, but in the same order. Which means that it's not enough to solve my case.

Comment: sadly that finds you every filename that contains *at least one* of `%mywords%` and is missing *at least one* of `%badwords%`. That doesn't match your criteria as stated in the question. (the "missing" part is ok, but you want *all* of `%mywords%`)

Comment: dammit, you're right. Now I remmember why I didn't use that yesterday -_-